# After selecting/clicking a radio button , at "goo.gl/RVdKM9" the status is still false

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


WebElement radmale = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='RESULT_RadioButton-8_0']"));

System.out.println(radmale.isDisplayed());

System.out.println(radmale.isEnabled()); 

System.out.println("Before selecting radio button , the status is:" + radmale.isSelected()); 
radmale.click();

// After click should be true, but still false why ??????
System.out.println("After selecting radio button , the status is:" + radmale.isSelected());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share html of the radio before and after selection.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the [`label`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) is selected, however you should rather be checking the associated [`input`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) instead.

So you need to introduce one more WebElement - for the radio input. It would be also good to execute [Element​.scroll​Into​View()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function in order to get confidence that the element is visible and can be interacted with.

Suggested updated code:

```
driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html");
WebElement radmale = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='RESULT_RadioButton-8_0']"));
WebElement radmaleInput = driver.findElement(By.id("RESULT_RadioButton-8_0"));
System.out.println(radmale.isDisplayed());

System.out.println(radmale.isEnabled());

System.out.println("Before selecting radio button , the status is:" + radmaleInput.isSelected());
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", radmale);
radmale.click();

// After click should be true, but still false why ??????
System.out.println("After selecting radio button , the status is:" + radmaleInput.isSelected());
```

Also be aware that it's recommended to go for [Page Object Model design pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) - this way you will be able to split test logic and DOM elements definitions hence your test code will always remain the same as it will be independent from the GUI part.